# Batch file to do svn export on multiple files only exports one file

Tags: svn, batch-file

I have this batch file to export two files from svn. But it never exports the second file, the output is "Export Complete."

I tried using IF statement and even PAUSE, it seems the command after the first svn export is never executed.

Here is my batch file: (Note that I only export two files, not two trees)

```
@ECHO off

svn export URL1
svn export URL2
```

Version:
Subversion 1.6.15,
Win7 32bit

Comment: What version of SVN / Windows are you using?  As this works on my machine with - svn 1.6.15 and Windows 7.

Comment: What you have described looks very much like `svn` being a batch file (with the actual executable being renamed something other accordingly). Could that possibly be the case? If so, Basiclife's suggestion about using `call svn` instead of `svn` should help, which you haven't reported yet whether it did.

Comment: It looks like the **svn** is a batch file (using **call svn** fixed my problem), but the question is, how do I find out the actual exe or batch file? I checked my **Path** and there is only Tortise SVN in it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried swapping the URLs? Is it still the 2nd that fails? Sorry to suggest the obvious but do you definitely have the correct URL?

Try putting a `Start` before each SVN call...

```
@ECHO OFF

Start svn export URL1
Start svn export URL2
```

This is equivalent to using Start->Run and typing in the commands. It should give some degree of separation.

Comment: individual svn export works. If I put "start" in the bat file, it works but too many windows pop up.

Comment: @AZ One other options - chae `Start` to `Call` - This may force it to continue in the same window...

Comment: Glad to hear it - Call is used to launch other processes but it does it in such a way that the process `exit` ing doesn't kill the batch file to allow you to handle return codes.

Answer (score 1):

Do both of your `export` commands work if you enter them manually?

If you place `echo` statements after each `svn export` command, do you see both of them?

Add the `--verbose` option and see if you get any more useful output.

Instead of `export`, try `svn log` and see if that command behaves the same.

*Update:* Hmm.. that sounds like the return from the first command is being interpreted as the return from the batch file.  Try combining them into one command: `command1 && command2`.  It's not a pretty solution, but it should work around the problem.

Comment: individual export works.    
It's wired, no echo output after the svn export command. It seems the batch file just exits.    
Subcommand 'export' doesn't accept option '-v [--verbose]'       
svn log does the same thing.